# Проброс трафика между двумя гостевыми ОС через виртуал бокс

Tags: виртуальная-машина

Имеется:

- Vbox 1 - XP, прокси сервер на 127.0.0.1:9951
- Vbox 2 - Android
- Хост - Debian

Задача. Дать андройду проксифицированный трафик из *Vbox 1*

Как реализовать?

На виртуалке с ХР стоит Vip72 который даёт прокси, что дальше делать?

Comment: Соединение на андроиде настроили с указанием прокси? Соединяетесь андроидом с хост-машиной или с роутером локалки?

Comment: В андройде решено не указывать настройки прокси, нужно реализовать именно интерфейсами виртуал бокса

Comment: @3amunyk Интерфейсами VirtualBox'а такую схему реализовать невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

1) К прокси, который слушает порт на адресах 127.*.*.*, может обращаться **только локальная машина**! Чтобы обращаться из сети, адрес должен быть либо 0.0.0.0, либо адресом одного из физических/виртуальных интерфейсов.

2) Чтобы трафик из Android шёл через прокси, и только через прокси, нужно чтобы у прокси было два интерфейса. Первый смотрит в Интернет (через NAT, сетевой мост и т.п.). Второй - внутренняя сеть в терминологии VirtualBox. У андроида один интерфейс, смотрящий в ту же внутреннюю сеть.

Чтобы это реализовать, в настройках виртуальной машины создаём второй интерфейс. Говорим, что это "внутренняя сеть", даём метку. В настройках андроида делаем то же самое. Обязательно указываем ту же самую метку. Потом даём новым интерфейсам на прокси и андроиде адреса из одной подсети (только адрес, шлюза и DNS быть не должно). Прокси должен слушать в том числе и адрес внутренней сети.

3) Можно подсоединить Android к NAT или сетевому мосту так же, как и прокси и указать прокси в настройках Android. Но при этом возможна утечка трафика напрямую без использования прокси. Чтобы этого избежать, уберите в настройках сети Android'а шлюз по умолчанию.

Comment: 2 пункт как реализовать ? я в приниципе так и предпологал, тока не могу разобратья.

Comment: @3amunyk Обновил ответ.

Comment: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1448713464.png
Ни чего не понимаю. Слева на скрине машина с прокси, справа временно xubuntu. Сети вообще нет, что я делаю не так ?

Comment: @3amunyk Адреса разных машин должны быть разными! Дайте xubuntu адрес 192.55.55.56. Но лучше эту подсеть не использовать, это "белые" адреса. Лучше взять что-нибудь из подсети 192.168.0.0/16. Только смотрите, чтобы с другими вашими подсетями не пересеклась.

Comment: Ой, это я уже устал просто, разумеется адреса давал разные.

Comment: Xubuntu даже не пингует внутрнеюю сеть ХР

Comment: @3amunyk То есть сама XP не пингуется? Отключите в ней брандмауэр, он может блокировать.

Comment: Да точно, спасибо, совсем забыл за брендмаузер. Стали пинговаться но X не имеет теперь интрнета. Хост и ДНС не прописывал.

Comment: Так у неё теперь и не будет интернета. Чтобы он был, надо прописать прокси в настройках нужной программы. Или в системе, если программа умеет оттуда брать.

Comment: Да, спасибо, действительно сеть заработала. Прокси поднялось. НО, разве нельзя реализовать тоже самое но на уровне виртуалбокса, что бы андройд уже на всё готовое цеплялся ? Без указания в самой ОС на прокси

Comment: @3amunyk Вы просили именно **прокси**. Схема с прокси работает именно так. Передать адрес прокси через DHCP невозможно. Возможно, Вам нужно не проксирование, а маршрутизация? В случае с маршрутизацией Интернет будет идти напрямую, мимо прокси-сервера, но через машину с XP. Или же Вам нужен прозрачный прокси? Вы определитесь точно, что именно Вам нужно.

Comment: Хмм, столько терминов мне не до конца известных, как бы правильно дать определение. В общем на винде я хочу просто раздавать прокси, а на клиенте подключатся к этим прокси просто выбрав нужный сетевой интрфейс в виртуал боксе, который будет знать как и где брать прокси и трафик, что бы предоставить это клиенту. Как то так... Но как ни курти и эта информация полезна, спасибо за потраченое время.

Comment: @3amunyk То, что Вы хотите, к сожалению, нереализуемо средствами VBox'а и Windows.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, вопрос решён.